# Ajuda com $filter angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtro

Estou fazendo um modal de pesquisa de telas de um sistema que estou fazendo, e estou encontrando o seguinte problema na hora de implementar o filtro: estou filtrando um array de objetos em um ng-repeat, cada objeto tem 3 campos, porém quero filtrar só dois, eu tentei fazer uma função tipo filter: getFiltered  e nela filtrar pelos 2 campos, porém não consegui guardar numa variável o array filtrado.

```
$scope.getFiltered = function(items){
    if(item.DescriptionSearch.indexOf($scope.comando.text) > -1){
        return true;
    }else if(item.Command != null){
        if(item.Command.indexOf($scope.comando.text) > -1){
            return true;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Uma dúvida, onde você está usando o `items` que está como parâmetro?